# Unable to fetch results from postgres

Tags: postgresql

Postgres not able to get results queried

```
opinion_db=# select * from verification_codes;
      user       | code  | id |          created_at           |          updated_at           | deleted_at 
-----------------+-------+----+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+------------
 eddie@gmail.com | 12345 |  1 | 2019-09-26 17:40:25.055544+00 | 2019-09-26 17:40:25.063162+00 | 
 eddie@gmail.com | 12345 |  2 | 2019-09-26 17:40:25.055544+00 | 2019-09-26 17:40:25.063162+00 | 
(2 rows)

opinion_db=# select * from verification_codes where user = 'eddie@gmail.com';
 user | code | id | created_at | updated_at | deleted_at 
------+------+----+------------+------------+------------
(0 rows)

opinion_db=#
```

The bytes stored are

```
opinion_db=# SELECT "user"::bytea FROM verification_codes;
                 user
----------------------------------
\x656464696540676d61696c2e636f6d
\x656464696540676d61696c2e636f6d
```

What is happening here??

Comment: What do you get for `SELECT "user"::bytea FROM verification_codes;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`user` refers to the database user.  You need `"user"` to refer to a column named "user".

You should not use database reserved words as column names, it is confusing, like here.